# What is the difference between "show" and "as" in an import statement?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

What is the difference between `show` and `as` in an import statement?

For example, what's the difference between

```
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;
```

and

```
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart' as GoogleMap;
```

When do I use `show` and when should I use `as`?

If I switch to `show GoogleMap` all references to `GoogleMap` (e.g. `GoogleMap.LatLng`) objects are reported as undefined.

Answer (score 245):

`as` and `show` are two different concepts.

With `as` you are giving the imported library a name. It's usually done to prevent a library from polluting your namespace if it has a lot of global functions. If you use `as` you can access all functions and classes of said library by accessing them the way you did in your example: `GoogleMap.LatLng`.

With `show` (and `hide`) you can pick specific classes you want to be visible in your application. For your example it would be:

```dart
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart' show LatLng;
```

With this you would be able to access `LatLng` but nothing else from that library. The opposite of this is:

```dart
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart' hide LatLng;
```

With this you would be able to access everything from that library except for `LatLng`.

If you want to use multiple classes with the same name you'd need to use `as`. You also can combine both approaches:

```dart
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart' as GoogleMap show LatLng;
```

Comment: What's the point of hiding imported functions?

Comment: If you import from 2 libraries which both contain a function or class with the same name, but you only want to use one of them and not use an alias using `as`, then you would hide the one you don't want to use.

Answer (score 30):

`show` case:

`import 'dart:async' show Stream;`

This way you only import `Stream` class from `dart:async`, so if you try to use another class from `dart:async` other than `Stream` it will throw an error.

```dart
void main() {
  List data = [1, 2, 3];
  Stream stream = new Stream.fromIterable(data); // doable
  StreamController controller = new StreamController(); // not doable
                                                        // because you only show Stream
}
```

`as` case:

`import 'dart:async' as async;`

This way you import all class from `dart:async` and namespaced it with `async` keyword.

```dart
void main() {
  async.StreamController controller = new async.StreamController(); // doable
  List data = [1, 2, 3];
  Stream stream = new Stream.fromIterable(data); // not doable
                                                 // because you namespaced it with 'async'
}
```

`as` is usually used when there are conflicting classes in your imported library, for example if you have a library 'my_library.dart' that contains a class named `Stream` and you also want to use `Stream` class from `dart:async` and then:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'my_library.dart';

void main() {
  Stream stream = new Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]);
}
```

This way, we don't know whether this Stream class is from async library or your own library. We have to use `as` :

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'my_library.dart' as myLib;

void main() {
  Stream stream = new Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]); // from async
  myLib.Stream myCustomStream = new myLib.Stream(); // from your library
}
```

For `show`, I guess this is used when we know we only need a specific class. Also can be used  when there are conflicting classes in your imported library. Let's say in your own library you have a class named `CustomStream` and `Stream` and you also want to use `dart:async`, but in this case you only need `CustomStream` from your own library.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'my_library.dart';

void main() {
  Stream stream = new Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]); // not doable
                                                   // we don't know whether Stream 
                                                   // is from async lib ir your own
  CustomStream customStream = new CustomStream();// doable
}
```

Some workaround:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'my_library.dart' show CustomStream;

void main() {
  Stream stream = new Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]); // doable, since we only import Stream
                                                   // async lib
  CustomStream customStream = new CustomStream();// doable
}
```

Comment: Does using `show` make the app size smaller since it isn't importing other things that aren't needed?

Comment: Flutter and dart2js, if not Dart generally, use tree-shaking to make app size smaller. See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33920

Answer (score 14):

`as` and `show` keywords used with library import statement. These two keywords are optional with `import` keyword, But using these keywords you can provide convenience and additional information about your library importing.

---

**`show`**

> `show` give restrictions to access only specific class of that library.

```
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;
```

Above dart:convert library contains more than 5 types of converters. (ascii,Base64,Latin1,Utf8 & json are some of them).

But with using `show` keyword you will give your application source file to access only that JSON converter class only.

*warning !! :- if you try to access any other converters like ascii, Base64 or Latin1, you will get an exception.
Because using `show` keyword you give an restriction for only access Json class in that library api.*

So if your source file want to access all the class in that library, you cannot define `show` keyword for that library importing.

---

**`as`**

> Provide additional namespace for library members.

This `as` keyword is mostly used when a library that contains lot of global functions.

- You will access static members of a library by Using the class name and . (dot operator).
  eg:- ClassName.staticFun()
- And also you will access instance methods and variables by using object name and . (dot operator) eg:- obj.instanceFunc()
- And also library source file can have **global functions**. and we will access them by their name without any parental membership. eg:-  func()

So when we access global functions of a different library inside our source file, we didnt have a way to seperatly identified that global function as seperate function of a different library.

But using `as` keyword, we can add namespace before accessing global functions of that library.

**See below example to understanding real benefit of `as` keyword.**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

http library contains lot of global functions. Below shows list of global functions in http library.

[image: List of http library global functions]

- Accessing above http library global functions **without** http namespace.( `import 'package:http/http.dart';` )

  ```
   eg:- 
     1.  get("url")

     2.  post("url")
  ```
- Accessing above http library global functions **with** http namespace. ( `import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;` )

  ```
   eg:- 
     1.  http.get("url")

     2.  http.post("url")
  ```

**So using `as` keyword , makes it easy to identify global functions of a different library separated from our source files' global functions.**

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the dart document, it's described in [Libraries and visibility](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility) section.

- `import as`: Specifying a library prefix, for example when import two libraries which has the same function name, then we can give them a prefix to specify the library.
- `import show`: This is used to import part of the library, `show` only import one name of the library.
- `import hide`: This is another one which is the opposite of the `show`, `hide` import all names except the name specified in the `hide`.