# Forward package member in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I import a package and would forward a member of it. What syntax does Dart offer for that?

**foo.dart**

```
import 'package:xzy/xzy.dart';  // contains class Xyz
// how do I forward Xyz here to make it available in bar.dart?
```

**bar.dart**

```
import 'package:mypackage/foo.dart';
Xyz is hidden here
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `export`

```
import 'package:xzy/xzy.dart'; 
export 'package:xzy/xzy.dart' show Xyz;
```

or just

```
export 'package:xzy/xzy.dart' show Xyz;
```

You don't need to import for that. Just export is enough if you don't need `Xyz` in this re-exporting file.

See also

- https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/create-library-packages
- [What is the difference between "show" and "as" in an import statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723063/what-is-the-difference-between-show-and-as-in-an-import-statement)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!