# What is the difference between these two packages importing ways in Dart language?

Tags: dart, flutter

There are two ways to import packages in Dart programming language, I need to know what is the difference between them both, please?
Also when to use the first way and when to use the second way?

First way:

```
import 'dart:io';
```

Second way

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
```

Comment: [This might help you understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723063/what-is-the-difference-between-show-and-as-in-an-import-statement)

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil yeah. That page has a lot of great nuggets related to this question

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil thank you very much this was very helpflul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as io` specifies a prefix.

Without you can use members `dart:io` exports like

```
var f = File();
```

with prefix it would be

```
var f = io.File();
```

This is useful to disambiguate imports if names collide with declarations in your current library or another imported library.

Packages like `path` assume that they are imported with a prefix, because it exports many top-level functions with common names that without a prefix would clutter the scope.