# Does Dart have import alias?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I found myself written tedious code when importing files into dart files like the following:

```
import '../../constants.dart';
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to create an alias to specific folder like:

```
import '@shared/constants.dart';
```

Thanks,
Javi.

Comment: It's not an aliases, but in Flutter there is way to make one import, which includes some different imports. Maybe it can help to shortened your imports

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Dart do not have import alias.

But you have absolute imports which makes up for it:

```
import 'package:my_lib/shared/constants.dart
```

This will import the file  `/lib/shared/constants.dart`

Comment: Worth noting that `my_lib` equals the `name` of your project in pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 54):

Dart doesn't allow you to rename imported identifiers, but it allows you to specify an import prefix

```
import '../../constants.dart' as foo;

...

foo.ImportedClass foo = foo.ImportedClass();
```

It allows also to filter imported identifiers like

```
import '../../constants.dart' show foo hide bar;
```

See also

- https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility
- [What is the difference between "show" and "as" in an import statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723063/what-is-the-difference-between-show-and-as-in-an-import-statement)

Barrel files can also make importing easier like

`lib/widgets/widgets.dart`

```dart
export 'widget1.dart';
export 'widget2.dart';
export 'widget3.dart';
export 'widget4.dart';
```

`lib/pages/page1.dart`

```dart
import '../widgets/widgets.dart';

Widget build(BuildContext context) => Widget1();
```

Comment: That's not what is asked for

Comment: I see. No there is no such thing. You can use `package:my_package/...` imports but that usually isn't shorter.

Comment: As commented by @RémiRousselet, I'd go for that solution.
Cheers guys :D

Comment: I just want to say thank you. As I past about 3 months learning Dart / Flutter, I easily know some basic concepts from your answers on Dart / Flutter topic on STO.