# Try using 'as prefix' for one of the imported directives,or hiding the name from all but one of the import

Tags: dart, flutter-dependencies, eos

I have imported a Eosdart package which have action.dart file and even flutter have action.dart file so there is conflict which one should pick.
 please help in removing the conflict
**i have mentioned the error detail as a comment in code where i have got the error**

```
class _AddBorrowerState extends State<AddBorrower> {
  eos.Account _account;
  eos.EOSClient _eosClient = eos.EOSClient(
      'http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80', 'v1',
      privateKeys: ["5JfVW2PtRkAcLbLETevxCwaQuT8NNWvP2eBYCrPRKPBWDgZDEo1"]);

  List<eos.Authorization> auth = [
    eos.Authorization()
      ..actor = 'guru11111111'
      ..permission = 'active'
  ];

  Map data = {
    'acc_name': myController1.text,**error only static member can be accessed in initializers**
    'b_id': '119',
    'location': 'mumbai',
    'b_phone': '11231212',
  };

  List<eos.Action> actions = [
    eos.Action()
      ..account = 'guru11111111'
      ..name = 'addborrower'
      ..authorization = auth   **ERROR only static member can be accessed in initializers**
      ..data = data**error only static member can be accessed in initializers**
  ];
  eos.Transaction transaction = eos.Transaction()..actions = actions;

  void _fetchEOSAccount() {
    _eosClient.getAccount(myController2.text).then((eos.Account account) {
      setState(() {
        _account = account;
      });
    });
  }

  void add() {
    _eosClient.pushTransaction(transaction, broadcast: true).then((trx) {
      print(trx);
    });
  }

  final myController1 = TextEditingController();
  final myController2 = TextEditingController();
  final myController3 = TextEditingController();
  final myController4 = TextEditingController();
  final myController5 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 25),
                child: TextField(**//these are textfeild who's value we want to store in eos table **
                  controller: myController1,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Enter Full Name',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 25),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: myController2,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Enter ID',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
               Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Submit'),
                  onPressed: () {
//                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    _fetchEOSAccount();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Text('${_account?.toJson()}'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ERROR:error only static member can be accessed in initializers,what does this means ? what should i do ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

**Edit**

myController1.text do not have value when initialize 
you can use empty string and update this value later in your future acion

use

```
import 'package:eosdart/eosdart.dart' as eos;
```

and in code prefiex with

```
eos.EOSClient(...)
```

also reference [Does Dart have import alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741749/does-dart-have-import-alias) 
and for show or hide reference [What is the difference between "show" and "as" in an import statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723063/what-is-the-difference-between-show-and-as-in-an-import-statement)

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:eosdart/eosdart.dart' as eos;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() {
  eos.EOSClient client = eos.EOSClient('http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'v1',
      privateKeys: ["5J9b3xMkbvcT6gYv2EpQ8FD4ZBjgypuNKwE1jxkd7Wd1DYzhk88"]);

  List<eos.Authorization> auth = [
    eos.Authorization()
      ..actor = 'bob'
      ..permission = 'active'
  ];

  Map data = {
    'from': 'bob',
    'to': 'alice',
    'quantity': '0.0001 SYS',
    'memo': '',
  };

  List<eos.Action> actions = [
    eos.Action()
      ..account = 'eosio.token'
      ..name = 'transfer'
      ..authorization = auth
      ..data = data
  ];

  eos.Transaction transaction = eos.Transaction()..actions = actions;

  // will print something like:
  // {transaction_id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, processed: {id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, block_num: 576745, block_time: 2019-05-03T06:07:54.500, producer_block_id: null, receipt: {status: executed, cpu_usage_us: 216, net_usage_words: 16}, elapsed: 216, net_usage: 128, scheduled: false, action_traces: [{receipt: {receiver: eosio.token, act_digest: 117d5840be4ff21fad764d5d497182916f76e772b279e65e964bccfa7c888331, global_sequence: 576794, recv_sequence: 17, auth_sequence: [[bob, 37]], code_sequence: 1, abi_sequence: 1}, act: {account: eosio.token, name: transfer, authorization: [{actor: bob, permission: active}], data: {from: bob, to: alice, quantity: 0.0001 SYS, memo: }, hex_data: 0000000000000e3d0000000000855c340100000000000000045359530000000000}, context_free: false, elapsed: 73, console: , trx_id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, block_num: 576745, block_time: 2019-05-03T06:07:54.500, producer_block_id: null, account_ram_deltas: [], except: null, inline_traces: [{receipt: {receiver: bob, act_digest: 117d5840be4ff21fad764d5d497182916f76e772b279e65e964bccfa7c888331, global_sequence: 576795, recv_sequence: 14, auth_sequence: [[bob, 38]], code_sequence: 1, abi_sequence: 1}, act: {account: eosio.token, name: transfer, authorization: [{actor: bob, permission: active}], data: {from: bob, to: alice, quantity: 0.0001 SYS, memo: }, hex_data: 0000000000000e3d0000000000855c340100000000000000045359530000000000}, context_free: false, elapsed: 2, console: , trx_id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, block_num: 576745, block_time: 2019-05-03T06:07:54.500, producer_block_id: null, account_ram_deltas: [], except: null, inline_traces: []}, {receipt: {receiver: alice, act_digest: 117d5840be4ff21fad764d5d497182916f76e772b279e65e964bccfa7c888331, global_sequence: 576796, recv_sequence: 15, auth_sequence: [[bob, 39]], code_sequence: 1, abi_sequence: 1}, act: {account: eosio.token, name: transfer, authorization: [{actor: bob, permission: active}], data: {from: bob, to: alice, quantity: 0.0001 SYS, memo: }, hex_data: 0000000000000e3d0000000000855c340100000000000000045359530000000000}, context_free: false, elapsed: 2, console: , trx_id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, block_num: 576745, block_time: 2019-05-03T06:07:54.500, producer_block_id: null, account_ram_deltas: [], except: null, inline_traces: []}]}], except: null}}
  client.pushTransaction(transaction, broadcast: true).then((trx) {
    print(trx);
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: problem is with push transaction method,do u have any demo for push transaction ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. use as keyword. could you post your code and error message?

Comment: i have added the code and error in comment please have a look

Comment: I have updated my answer. myController1.text do not have value when initialize this page.

Comment: sir please check this link and answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/57953832/12072674

Comment: sir please check this link,it have same question but well defined

Comment: Glad to help. please make this as answer If this answer help you in this specific question. please ignore this message if it does not help you.

Answer (score 32):

Another solution is to hide `Action` from `material.dart`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Action;
```

Comment: definitely a wise option

Answer (score 0):

This bugs is coming normally because you are trying to call method with two imported library have two property with the same name
1   : SOLUTIONS : import first or second class as prefix :
E.g :
`import dart.io  ] as httpIO import dart.http`

Call [httpIO] prefix for using the property from dart.io and call property from dart.http in the traditional way : Object.property_name