# Why I can't use this class Platform in Flutter even though it's installed

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

This error got me confusing since I can't use the class Platform but I have already added its library dart.io (and even upgraded the pubspec file). The strange thing is that the class appears :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoGOU.png)

but when Im using it, it throws an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cumum.png)

any idea if it is a flutter bug?

Comment: You are importing both the `'dart:html'` and `'dart:io' packages, both of which define a `Platform` class, and the analyzer doesn't know which one you are trying to reference. You need to label one of the imports such as `import 'dart:io' as io;` and then use the label to specify which one you want like `io.Platform.isAndroid`. (And on a separate note, you shouldn't import both of these packages as they are mutually exclusive. Only import one or the other depending on if this is for mobile/desktop development or for web development.)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951672/try-using-as-prefix-for-one-of-the-imported-directives-or-hiding-the-name-from) helps?

Comment: Change import path to `import 'dart:io' as io;` and use `io.Platform.isAndroid`.

Comment: exactly the problem. I would never think of this, thank you guys