# After I update the flutter there's an import error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

/C:/Users/DL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:6:1: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart';
datetime_picker_theme.dart:1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/DL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:199:31: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
this.theme = theme ?? DatePickerTheme(),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.

this error happens after I update

Comment: Just run 'flutter pub get' and then if it doesn't work then restart your IDE and this should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Seem likes the new updated Flutter has it own material `datetime_picker_theme` & you also use `datetime_picker_theme` in package `flutter_datetime_picker`. You could use the alias for import package, check out: [Does Dart have import alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741749/does-dart-have-import-alias)

If your previous `datetime_picker_theme` belongs to package `flutter_datetime_picker`, you could make a alias for it, such as:

```
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart' as fl_dt_picker;
```

And then use your `DatePickerTheme()`.

Comment: on the main dart sir?

Comment: do you know which file makes that error? Or it fails at compile-time without knowing which file makes error?

Comment: /C:/Users/DL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:

Comment: oh, did you try to remove `flutter_datetime_picker` from pubspect.yaml? It's kinda old, i think remove wouldn't be a problem

Comment: I used the method that youve given  using "as" but now theres an error on my project showTimePicker showDatePicker

Answer (score 0):

problem: DatePickerTheme class conflict in 2 different pub package

possible solution:

1. try to check the changes from pub packages, and figure out the broken changes,
2. theres 2 class DatePickerTheme exist in 2 different packages, try to import them "as" similar to this [dart import](https://dart.dev/language/libraries)

example

```
import 'package:lib1/lib1.dart';

import 'package:lib2/lib2.dart' as lib2;

// Uses Element from lib1.
Element element1 = Element();

// Uses Element from lib2.
lib2.Element element2 = lib2.Element();
```