# problem with auto_route package after upgrading flutter to 1.22.0

Tags: flutter, dart

yesterday, I've upgraded flutter to version 1.22.0, and every thing is ok except of this error

> Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.
> Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'T' which doesn't work:
> Type parameter 'T' declared to extend 'RouterBase'.
> The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:
> Parameter 'router' declared as     'T'
> but argument is 'dynamic'.
> Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

this  is the code I have

```
return MaterialApp(
builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder(router: Router()),
...
);
```

I'm using the auto_route package

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a Type to be associated with the builder constructor now.

try this,

```
import 'auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'router.gr.dart' as r;


  return MaterialApp(
   builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder<r.Router>(router: r.Router()),
   ...
  );
```

I faced issues that Router was defined in multiple files so use an alias while importing if you face such an issue like above.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to conflict between Router class in library 'package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart' and the generated file 'router.gr.dart'.

If you are not using the Router class from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart' in the same file you can hide it while importing material package.

Like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Router;
```

[More info on hide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19723473)