# Flutter, import show keyword

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;
```

As far as I know the "show" keyword bring the only one class from library right

but I can`t find now JSON class where is it? I jumped to dart:convert and then I don`t see any on "Class JSON"

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, JSON is not a class from `dart:convert`. What you might want is `json`:

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show json;
```

Which **is** defined in the `dart:convert` librart in the `json.dart` file:

[image]

Comment: I can see the part 'json.dart'; this is it?? it could be a file name, not just a class? because I can see the "class json" either

Comment: can you please answer above question?? so I can adopt this

Comment: It's an instance of a class, I updated my answer to include an image of the source code. Otherwise you can ctrl+click to see it for yourself

Comment: there is it.. so hard to find thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723063/what-is-the-difference-between-show-and-as-in-an-import-statement    this one uses show JSON what do you think?

Comment: You don't need to use `show` unless some class names conflict with one defined in your file.